# HTML page, iPad orientation change redraws incorrectly - displays split view

Tags: html, ios, ipad, orientation

I'm having a problem on a web page where an orientation change (landscape to portrait, or portrait to landscape) causes the window to display incorrectly:

The display reorients, correctly for a brief instance, and then an incorrectly scaled column appears on the left hand side.  The incorrectly scaled portion of the window is part of the pre-rotated page (oriented correctly).

Reloading the page fixes the problem (until the next orientation change).

At the moment, I only have an iPad mini 7.0.3 to test on.
For tablets, there is no orientation change function, and this displays fine on Android tablets.

I can't find anything online about this... is it a known bug?

The viewport meta looks like:

`<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=yes'>`

------------------------ update: ------------------------

I whittled down the page, and the results are:
1. I have included some fonts from http://openfontlibrary.org
 
2. I have a `<ul>` on the page

If I remove *either* of these, the problem goes away!  (probably something other than `<ul>` will cause this as well, since at least one of the pages shows the problem without this tag).

Will research further... it would be a shame if I couldn't embed fonts!

Comment: Do you have a link to the live page or a fiddle that recreates the issue?

Comment: Haven't had a chance to reduce problem yet, wondering if anyone's heard of such a thing.

Comment: Are you using JS to size anything on the page?

Comment: not on orientation change, there's no bound handler for tablets. (quick check says not at all, in fact-- just padding changes and the like on initial load)

Comment: I've used embedded fonts and never had this issue. Do you have a link to the live site?

Comment: I have too... but something's amiss (removing 'topbanner' will correct the problem as well)    http://www.eyebright.net/ipadtst1/

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding this to your body tag:

`onresize="location.reload()"`

this should reload the page when the vieuwport changes.